# Testing multiple numeric columns to make new column

Tags: r, conditional-statements, numeric, logical-operators

I would like to create a new numeric column which is assigned values based on a threshold of multiple numeric columns.

```
Data<-data.frame(A=rnorm(100), B=rnorm(100), C=rnorm(100), D=rnorm(100), E=rnorm(100))
```

Basically if any of the columns A, B or C exceed 2 I would like to assign a 5 to my new column. I have tried:

```
  Data$Flag[if((abs(Data$A)>2 | abs(Data$B)>2 | abs(Data$C)>2)] <-5
```

Which doesn't work. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would like:

```
Data$Flag <- ifelse((abs(Data$A)>2 | abs(Data$B)>2 | abs(Data$C)>2), 5, NA)
```

Replace `NA` with the alternative value for when they are not all over 2.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:

```
Data$Flag1 <- NA^(!rowSums(abs(Data[,c('A', 'B', 'C')]) >2)) +4
identical(Data$Flag, Data$Flag1) #Comparing the results from @Robert Krzyzanowski
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```
Data$Flag[rowSums(abs(Data[c("A","B","C")]) > 2) > 0] <- 5
```